# MVC 4 EF Update failed Object Already Exists In The ObjectStateManager

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this relationship for my tables. `Activity`, `Workstation`, `Platform`, `Part` are the lookup tables.

I have `ActivitWorkstation` that contains `(ActivityId, WorkstationId)` foreign keys to `Activity` and `Workstation` tables.

I also have `PlatformPart` that contains `(PlatformId, PartId)` foreign keys to `Platform` and `Part` tables.

Lastly I have `PartStaging` table that has `(ActivityWorkstationId, PlatformPartId)` foreign keys to `ActivityWorkstation` and `PlatformPart` tables.

Below is my `PartStaging` Edit method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(PartStagingVM partstagingvm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        PartStaging partstaging = new PartStaging();

        var activityWorkstation = db.ActivityWorkstations.FirstOrDefault(aw => aw.ActivityId == partstagingvm.ActivityId && aw.WorkstationId == partstagingvm.WorkstationId);

        if (activityWorkstation == null)
        {
            activityWorkstation = new ActivityWorkstation
            {
                ActivityId = partstagingvm.ActivityId,
                WorkstationId = partstagingvm.WorkstationId
            };

            db.Entry(activityWorkstation).State = EntityState.Added;
        }

        var platformPart = db.PlatformParts.FirstOrDefault(pp => pp.PlatformId == partstagingvm.PlatformId && pp.PartId == partstagingvm.PartId);

        if (platformPart == null)
        {
            platformPart = new PlatformPart
            {
                PlatformId = partstagingvm.PlatformId,
                PartId = partstagingvm.PartId
            };

            db.Entry(platformPart).State = EntityState.Added;
        }

        var partStaging = db.PartStagings.FirstOrDefault(ps => ps.ActivityWorkstationId == activityWorkstation.Id && ps.PlatformPartId == platformPart.Id);

        if (partStaging != null && partStaging.Id != partstagingvm.Id)
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "The record already exists.";
        }
        else
        {
            partstaging.Id = partstagingvm.Id;
            partstaging.ActivityWorkstationId = activityWorkstation.Id;
            partstaging.PlatformPartId = platformPart.Id;
            partstaging.Description = partstagingvm.Description;

            db.Entry(partstaging).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            TempData["Message"] = "The record has been modified.";
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Edit");
    }

    return View(partstagingvm);
}
```

I can edit `ActivityWorkstation`. I can edit `PlatformPart`.  It prevents me from updating when the record already exists.  But I have a problem when editing the `Description`.  It's supposed to be the simplest update since all I have to do is to assign:

```
partstaging.Description = partstagingvm.Description
```

But when I submit, I get this error:

```
An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

Source Error: 


Line 216:                    partstaging.Description = partstagingvm.Description;
Line 217:
Line 218:                    db.Entry(partstaging).State = EntityState.Modified;
Line 219:                    db.SaveChanges();
Line 220:
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I doubt if you can just assign another `Id` to the `partstaging` coming from `var partStaging = db.PartStagings.FirstOrDefault(ps => ps.ActivityWorkstationId == activityWorkstation.Id && ps.PlatformPartId == platformPart.Id);`. What's the idea?

Comment: The idea was to check first if the record with the same combination (ActivityIdWorkstationId, PlatformPartId) existed or not.  If there's a record already, don't insert.